# First test fails on IntelliJ IDEA + Appium

Tags: java, intellij-idea, automation, testng, appium

I'm a new one to automation. I've set up an environment for test automation, but I'm unable to run my first test, errors occurs on each run. Have no idea what it is, please help me
Here is my code:

```
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class FirstTest {

    AndroidDriver androidDriver;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("devicename", "Testdevice");
        androidDriver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }

    @Test
    public void logInCheck() throws Exception {
        androidDriver.findElement(By.id("com.example.mariia.testing:id/button")).click();
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        androidDriver.quit();
    }
}
```

Here are the errors that i'm receiving:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at FirstTest.logInCheck(FirstTest.java:34)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:85)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:639)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:816)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:774)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:624)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:359)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:354)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:312)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:261)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1215)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1140)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1048)
at org.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:74)
at org.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:124)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't set capabilities `platformName`, `platformVersion`,`app` and `deviceName`. You're testing Android app, so You need to provide additionally capabilites `appActivity` and `appPackage`.

Answer (score 0):

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
caps.SetCapability("app-package", "com.myapp.test");
caps.SetCapability("browserName", "");
caps.SetCapability("device", "Android");
caps.SetCapability("app-activity", "com.myapp.SplashActivity");
caps.SetCapability("version", "4.1.2");
caps.SetCapability("device ID", "uniquedeviceid");
caps.SetCapability("app", "apk-path");
```

To narrow down your issue, please provide your testng.xml file.